# "No provisioned iPhone OS Device connected error message"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have finished making an iPhone app, and I would like to put it on my iPhone. If it is possible I would like to do it without paying the $99 a year to Apple. I am running OSX 10.6.5 and iOS 4.0.1 and XCode 3.2.3. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a valid provisioning profile on your phone to do that, and this entails paying apple $99.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly encourage you to pay the fee and start developing with a fully functional non-jailbreaking iDevice. My own experience is that with a jailbreaking device things just tend to get weird. Small but fatal bugs do happen.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done legally without paying the fee.

Comment: I don't think the term is 'legally'. Jailbreaking is legal in the USA.

Comment: Touche; replace it with "in a way that Apple would approve of."

Answer (score 0):

The only way to develop for iOS without paying the annual fee to Apple is by 'jailbreaking' your phone.

Comment: I have already done that. Do you know of a way that I can use that to get my app on my iPhone?